# Getting NaN using += operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get combined heights of two divs with the same class on a page. When I do it the first way, I get NaN as a result, but checking the console, there are only two results being added, both of type number.

(This results in NaN)

```
$scope.getPageHeader = function () {
  var headerSize;
  var myArr = [];
  var pageHeaders = jQuery(".page-header");

  jQuery(pageHeaders).each(function () {
    headerSize += jQuery(this).height();
    // myArr.push(jQuery(this).height());
    // headerSize =  myArr[0] + myArr[1];

  })
  return headerSize;
}
```

If I try do it the long winded way, of pushing the two items onto an array and adding them, it works. Why is this?

(This results in the correct number being returned)

```
$scope.getPageHeader = function () {
  var headerSize;
  var myArr = [];
  var pageHeaders = jQuery(".page-header");

  jQuery(pageHeaders).each(function () {
    //headerSize += jQuery(this).height();
    myArr.push(jQuery(this).height());
    headerSize =  myArr[0] + myArr[1];

  })
  return headerSize;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Initialize `headerSize` to 0 because `isNaN(undefined + 0)`

Answer (score 1):

In the first example the headerSize value is undefined to start, so when you add to it you get NaN.

Initialize it to zero on declaration and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

code should be

```
$scope.getPageHeader = function () {
  var headerSize = 0;
  var myArr = [];
  var pageHeaders = jQuery(".page-header");

  jQuery(pageHeaders).each(function () {
    headerSize += jQuery(this).height();
  })
  return headerSize;
}
```